# How to sort NSArray by NSMutableDictonary's value

Tags: objective-c

I want to try sort by `NSMutableDictionary`'s value which key is  `price` in people which is `NSMutableArray`.

like this...

```
people = [
  ["price" => 133, "name" => "banana"],
  ["price" => 333,"name" => "apple"],
  ["price" => 3, "name" => "orange"],
]
```

I want to like this:

```
copiedPeople = [
  ["price" => 3, "name" => "orange],
  ["price" => 133,"name" => "banana"],
  ["price" => 333, "name" => "apple"],
]
```

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sortUsingComparator:` lets you pass in a block which says how to sort items. So you can do this:

```
[people sortUsingComparator: ^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
    return [[obj1 objectForKey: @"price"] compare: [obj2 objectForKey: @"price"]];
}];
```

EDIT: just saw your edit... you can use `sortedArrayUsingComparator:` on NSArray to create a new sorted array.